# How can I run a search list using Youtube API v3?

Tags: node.js, typescript, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to run a search list using Youtube API v3.
I've run the `quickstart.js` in order to configure my OAuth2 as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs) and apparently everything worked saying `This channel's ID is UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM91Ttw. Its title is 'Google Developers', and it has 181445346 views.`

Typescript code:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import {
  google,   // The top level object used to access services
  Auth,     // Namespace for auth related types
} from 'googleapis';


const auth: Auth.GoogleAuth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth();
const youtube = google.youtube({
  version: 'v3',
  auth,

});
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  youtube.search.list({
    part: ['id, snippet'],
    maxResults: 10,
    q: 'my query search'
  })
  .then( results => {
    res.send(results);
  })
  .catch( err => {
    res.send(err);
  })
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3300;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app is listening on PORT: ${port}`))
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/Users/username/dev/my-project/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:173:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/Users/suername/dev/my-project/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:545:17)
    at async GoogleAuth.request (/Users/username/dev/my-project/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:598:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I forgot to set the `option.auth: API_KEY`

Comment: Where and how did you set that option.auth?